# Strengthening a given attack on discrete log

Tags: cryptography, number-theory, group-theory

I am trying to prove the following claim:

> Let $(G,*)$ be a cyclic group of size $m$ with generator $g$. Assume
> there exists some adversary $A'$ of size
> $T'=\frac{\left(T-O\left(\log m\right)\right)}{2}$, for some
> $T$, such that $$\mathbb{P}_{b\gets
>  G}\left[A'(b)=\log_{g}(b)\right]>\frac{1}{2}.$$ Show that there exists
> an adversary $A$ of size $T$ such that $$\mathbb{P}_{b\gets
>  G}\left[A(b)=\log_{g}(b)\right]>\frac{3}{4}.$$
> Assume multiplication over $G$ requires $O(1)$ circuit.

How can I prove this claim? Intuitively, since $A$ is bigger than $A'$ in about $O(\log m)$, the construction should be based on dividing the problem into halfs recursively, as in binary search. However, I can't think of any clever way to do that...

Comment: Use randomized self-reducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we had a stronger guarantee: $A'$ is a randomized algorithm, and for every $b$, $\Pr[A'(b) = \log_g b] > 1/2$, *over the randomness of the algorithm*. In that case, you would construct $A$ by running $A'$ several times, and checking each output until you get one that satisfies $g^{A'(b)} = b$.

Now suppose that the guarantee is $\Pr_b[A'(b) = \log_g b] > 1/2$. You would like to somehow get "independent samples" of $A'(b)$. You can accomplish that using randomized self-reducibility. I'll let you fill that out since it's your exercise. The resulting algorithm is randomized, but by choosing the optimal randomness, you get a deterministic (but non-uniform) algorithm with the same guarantees.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I have a small question. You suggested sampling $A'(b)$ several times to get a better estimation for $\log_g (b)$. However, we assume $b$ is chosen uniformly over $G$ and $A'$ returns some value when given $b$. So if $A'$ is a deterministic algorithm, it would always return the same outputs for the same inputs. In other words, if we keep feeding it with some fixed $b$ we have sampled, it will keep giving us the same result over and over... I'm a little confused here

Comment: This is the part that requires randomized self-reducibility.

Comment: I eventually used the following method. I sample $a_1,a_2, a_3 \gets \mathbb{Z}_m$, and calculate $g_i \gets X\cdot g^{a_i}$ for each. Later I calculate $b_i \gets A'(g_i)$. After that I search for some $i$ such that $b_i =a_i$, and if I find one, I return $b_i-a_i \mod m$.
Does it look ok?

Comment: Why do you need $b_i = a_i$? Also, note that if $b_i = a_i$ then $b_i-a_i \bmod m = 0$.

Comment: My mistake. You need to compare $g_i$ with $g^{b_i}$, and if they are equal you return $b_i - a_i \mod m$, since $X=g^{b_i-a_i}$

Comment: Right, that's the idea.